# Extract multiple dates from string in Javascript with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, date, parsing

I am new to regex, and have looked all over, though I could not find an exact regex that works. There are no whitespaces in the string, and the dates can be surrounded by any random text, non-date, characters.

### Sample Strings and expected responses:

### EX 1:

```
From2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMember_currency_CNY  
var res = ['2017-01-01', '2017-12-31']
```

### EX 2:

```
From2016-01-01to2016-12-31  
var res = ['2016-01-01', '2016-12-31']
```

### EX 3:

```
From2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMember  
var res = ['2017-01-01', '2017-12-31']
```

### EX 4:

```
AsOf2017-12-31  
var res = ['2017-12-31']
```

I have teted this regex (among others), with no avail:
`/\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b/g`

I was using this tool to test:
http://rubular.com/r/bce4IHyCjW

Comment: Just reminding that regex has some limitations, because it'll match things like `2017-02-29` (February **29**th, but 2017 isn't a leap year) and `2017-04-31` (April **31**st, but April has 30 days), not to mention cases like `9999-99-99`. Actually, with regex, you'll get a list of **possible dates** (things that look like dates), but you'll have to validate them later if you want to make sure they're really valid dates. Of course you can ignore this if you can guarantee that the inputs always have valid dates.

Answer (score 2):

You do not match the dates because the word boundary `\b` does not match for example between `m2`

Try it without the word boundary `\b`

[`\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/Pvnuqb/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "From2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMember_currency_CNY",
  "From2016-01-01to2016-12-31",
  "From2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMe",
  "AsOf2017-12-31"
];
let pattern = /\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/g;
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will check this out!

Comment: Thanks I ran the snippet and I see the values as expected, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove word-boundary `\b`

```
var regex =  /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/g
```

**Demo**

```js
var str1 = "2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMember_currency_CNY";
var str2 = "From2016-01-01to2016-12-31";
var str3 = "From2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMember";
var str4 = "AsOf2017-12-31";

var regex =  /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/g

console.log( str1.match(regex) );
console.log( str2.match(regex) );
console.log( str3.match(regex) );
console.log( str4.match(regex) );
```

Comment: Thank you, this one helps as well!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
/(?:^|\D)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?!\d)/g
```

Extract Group 1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6flIE2/1).

Here, `(?:^|\D)` matches a start of a string (`^`) or (`|`) any char other than a digit (`\D`). The `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

JS Demo:

```js
var strs = ["From2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMember_currency_CNY","From2016-01-01to2016-12-31", "From2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMember", "AsOf2017-12-31" ];
var rx = /(?:^|\D)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?!\d)/g;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s);
  var res=[], m;
  while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
     res.push(m[1]);
  }
  console.log(res);
}
```

With the browsers supporting ECMA 2018 standard (that supports lookbehinds),

```
/(?<!\d)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?!\d)/g
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6flIE2/3). The `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the left of the current location.

JS Demo:

```js
var strs = ["From2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMember_currency_CNY","From2016-01-01to2016-12-31", "From2017-01-01to2017-12-31_custom_EquityPurchaseAgreementMember_custom_FirstPaymentMember", "AsOf2017-12-31" ];
var rx = /(?<!\d)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?!\d)/g;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", s.match(rx));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the date values can be `1-1-2015` or `01-25-2015` so to make your regex more general you should use this regex

```
var regex = /([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)/g
```

and you can use this website to test your regex it's awesome and can generate the code for some languages too [regex101](https://regex101.com/)